# Solving the one-dimensional heat equation in an infinite rod by separation of variables and comparing to Fourier Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, heat-equation

I want to solve the the one-dimensional heat equation in an infinite rod with the initial condition that all the heat is initially concentrated at $x=0$, so 
 $u(x,0)=\delta(x)$. The boundary condition is $u(\infty,t) = 0$

In the first 3 pages of the following paper, the one-dimensional heat equation in an infinite rod is solved by separation of variables.

https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-303-linear-partial-differential-equations-fall-2006/lecture-notes/fourtran.pdf

It is specifically mentioned in the first line of the second page that $u \to 0$ ad $x \to \infty$

This does not seem to be consistent with the fact that 
 $$X(x) = A \cos (\sqrt{\lambda}x) + B \sin (\sqrt{\lambda}x) \ne 0 $$

as $\ x \to \infty $

If I however apply my initial condition to the final result (equation 8 in the paper) then I obtain a Gaussian type function that does have the right boundary conditions: $u \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$.

Other threads on this forum have indicated that this problem should be solved with the Fourier transform method.

My question then becomes: How does this paper seem to get the right final answer through separation of variables, even with the boundary condition $u(\infty,t) = 0$? The solution in the paper for $X(x)$ does not satisfy the boundary condition, but the final solution does. It seems like this paper is cutting some corners in a mathematically less rigorous way to obtain the right answer, but I can't find out exactly where.

Comment: Did you read through the entire paper? The final solution, in integral form, does go to $0$ as $x\to\infty$

Comment: Hello Dylan, thanks for the comment. My problem is exactly that the final solution is correct, and does conform to the boundary conditions that I have imposed, but that the boundary condition does not hold for the X(x) function above. I can solve the diffusion equation as well through a Fourier Transform and obtain the same answer. I would like, however, to compare the two different techniques.

In another thread on this forum, the same problem is mentioned: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221550/heat-equation-separation-of-variables-and-fourier-transform

Comment: The second answer states: First of all, the only solution of A″+γA=0 such that limx→±∞A(x)=0 is A(x)≡0 (A being X in my notation). I would tend to agree with this statement, but then the paper still obtains the overall right solution. So my question is how not respecting the boundary condition in X(x) still gives the right solution in the end. I hope my question is clear.