# Can I use separation of variables to solve the heat equation on an infinitely long rod

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, boundary-value-problem

The heat equation in 1D is:
$$
\frac{\partial  T(x,t)}{\partial t}  = \alpha \,\frac{\partial^2T(x,t)}{\partial x^2} \, , \quad \alpha > 0
$$
My IC's and BC's
\begin{cases}
T'_x(0,t) = T'_x(L,t) = 0 \\
T(x,0) = f(x)
\end{cases}
I made the assumption that
$$ T(x,t) = F(x)G(t) $$
Meaning that I get 2 dimensionally independent ODEs:
\begin{cases}
\frac{F''_x(x)}{F(x)} = \lambda\ \\[2mm]
\alpha \, \frac{G'_t(t)}{G(t)} = \lambda 
\end{cases}
Ending up with the solutions
$$ T_n(x,t) = C_n\, \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right)\, e^{ \, - \frac{n^2\pi^2}{\alpha L^2}t} \, .$$
Which can be linearly superposed to have:
$$T(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\, \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right)\, e^{ \, -\frac{n^2\pi^2}{\alpha L^2}t}\, $$

Can I do the same thing for an infinitely long rod by changing my BC's to (for example)
\begin{cases}
\lim_{n \to \infty} T'_x(-n,t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} T'_x(n,t) = 0 \\[3mm]
T(x,0) = f(x)
\end{cases}
Or should I solve the heat equation using a different method?

Comment: Using a finite rod gives the discrete wavelength $\sin$ solutions as you have shown. I believe the only difference when solving on an infinite rod is that your $\sin$ components are not discrete, so you would need to use a Fourier transform rather than a Fourier series to get the solution when solving an IVP in time (imposing $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}T(x,0) = 0$) although I could be wrong.

Comment: @RyanK So I could simply take a Fourier transform of the whole pde and then simplify things, and then take the inverse Fourier transform?

Comment: Your solution $T(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\, \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L} \right)\, e^{ \, -\frac{n^2\pi^2}{\alpha L^2}t}$ will change to an integral over $\sin$ wavelengths rather than a sum, you can find the appropriate coefficients with the inverse Fourier transform on the initial condition.

Comment: I believe [this MSE post in the related tab](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221550/heat-equation-separation-of-variables-and-fourier-transform?rq=1) is closely related to what you are looking for.